# Can not import tensorflow - weird error alert

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

When I try to import tensorflow using

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I get the following error:

```
module 'tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal' has no attribute 'TFE_DEVICE_PLACEMENT_SILENT_FOR_INT32'
```

Is anyone can think of a solution to this problem? Thank you.

I tried to search this error on google and here on stack overflow but could not find anything. 
If any more data on my PC is required for solving this, please tell me and I'll add it.

Comment: Did you face this problem after installation of after sometime using it?

Comment: Hi! I encountered this problem after trying to install a version of tf for gpu. after I've realised that tf is not competable with my kind of gpu, I tried to use it again on my cpu, but this problem accured.